# Picom compositor conflicts

Tags: cinnamon, composite, picom

I am on Arch using Xorg, lightdm, and Cinnamon. When I try to run Picom in Cinnamon I get:

```
~$ picom
[ 11/20/22 23:52:28.630 session_init FATAL ERROR ] Another composite manager is already running
```

I understand that there is another compositor running apparently, so I installed inxi to check, and when I run `~$ inxi -Gxx | grep compositor` it returns nothing. I have used i3 with Picom on this same installation and it works flawlessly. I don't see why it's not working in Cinnamon.

My question is, can I change the settings to give Picom override permissions over other compositors? If not, how should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Won't work with cinnamon, since it has "mutter" as compositor in its core. As opposed to XFCE, where the compositor can be turned off (and picom used) cinnamon and gnome3/4 are not modular enough  to turn anything off.

Using XFCE4 (which has less GPU glitches) with picom is the lightest usage of compositing I've encountered so far (using it on my old Thinkpad R61i)

Comment: thank you! this was for my thinkpad x60s lol